# Why is the .toc file created at end document?

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files, latex-base

To create a Table of Contents (for example), LaTeX2e follows the process:

- Run 1

  - `.aux` file is created from scratch after `\begin{document}`.
  - When processing section headers, write `\addtocontents` to the `.aux` file with the pertinent sectioning information.
  - At `\end{document}`, `\input` the `.aux` file, which executes `\@writefile` via `\contentsline` to generate the `.toc` file.
- Run 2

  - At `\begin{document}`, deactivate `\@writefile` and re-input the `.aux` file. This generates labelling information, etc., for the current compilation and has no effect on the `.toc` file already generated.
  - After `\begin{document}`, the `.aux` file is opened for writing, which clears its contents. The process starts anew.

The `2e` sources don't go into detail about why the system was designed this way. Since there are limited write registers, writing all `.toc` information in one pass at `\end{document}` minimises the number of files that need to be kept open during the document. So that aspect is sensible.

But why is the `.aux` file input both at the beginning *and* the end of the document? Couldn't the `.toc` file be generated at `\begin{document}` instead?

(One difference is that if ‘Run 1’ is terminated prematurely, no `.toc` file will be generated at all so there'll be no ToC. Whereas if the `.toc` file were created at `\begin{document}` it would  contain a partial ToC — but that's arguably no better or worse. And you could add, say, a `\@finishedauxtrue` flag inserted at `\end{document}` to catch this happening if necessary.)

[[**EDIT**: Well, loading the `aux` file at the end allows for some checking whether labels have changed, and so on. So the `aux` file does always need to be loaded twice; I guess my question is whether there's any difference for ToC generation when that happens.]]

Comment: My uneducated guess is that it is a historical artifact left over from the days of small memory machines, where the whole document may not fit in the computer memory at once.  In such a case, it makes sense to make a pass through the document, doing what can be done on each pass.  Today, things like MikTeX automate the process of running as many passes as necessary to get the job done.  Back in the day, running successive passes would seem to be a very efficient approach.  Bottom line: the aux file cannot be completed at `\begin{documement}` without a full document pass.

Comment: But wouldn't you still have to input the `aux` file twice? Once with `@writefile` active and once with it inactive?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes — I'm not trying to argue against the current multi-pass mechanism; I don't think you can ever get away from it entirely. You can feasibly get document structure and other `nonlinear' material by preprocessing the document syntax, but resolving cross-references inherently requires multiple typesetting passes. Whether that's done externally (as now) or internally doesn't make too much difference IMO.

Comment: I agree.  My point only was that, at a time when memory was more precious, doing it "internally" may not have been an option.  Thus, the current approach may be vestigial.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are certainly several ways to implement a data transport mechanism between runs. The LaTeX one attempts to be rather economically with resources.

There are a number of tasks that it caters for:

- TOC-type files are only generated if the document asks for a TOC. This only becomes clear somewhere within the document (i.e., not automatically available at `\begin{document}`) so this favors writing the TOC file at the end (not at the beginning). Otherwise you either have to always write them or carry that information from one run to the next (which is not possible via the aux file as it has to be known at the start of reading the aux file).
- For the same reason directly writing the TOC file (rather than using the aux file as an intermediate) is not possible (unless you always generate them and the toc comes either at the very beginning or the very end of the document). Also reusing parts of the toc data, e.g., for chapter tocs, would then be impossible.
- Rereading the aux file at the end is not only there for generating the TOCs but also to post process the data, e.g., cross-reference checking, so it is needed in any case.
- Reading the aux file at the beginning is necessary to obtain the data from the previous run (e.g., cross references).

So yes, one could produce the TOC-type files at the beginning, but then would either need an additional mechanism to pass the info which files to generate or one would need to produce them always, even if there is no TOC or LOT or ... being asked for. In short there is no gain (only loss).

Unless you want to read in the whole document in memory there is no way to avoid a multi-pass system (well it would be multi-pass even then) and keeping the whole document in memory is not economical with TeX and in fact not really with any system. So it was/is not a historical artifact because of small memory, it is a general necessity.

Comment: Directly writing the TOC file is impossible because it must be open for writing, but closed for reading. The only possibility for doing it is having the table of contents as the last thing in the document (which is what `texinfo` does, IIRC) and this is not an option for a normal document.

Comment: @egreg right, it is only possible if it comes either first or last but not if the toc potentially comes somewhere in the middle (that's what I meant). Also it would not allow to reuse the TOC data partially, e.g., for chapter tocs. I guess I could have said this slightly better; slightly updated now.