# Why do we need to compile twice to see the changes in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

I'm using Texmaker 4.4.1 as an editor and MiKTeX 2.9 as a compiler. When ever I create table of contents (`\tableofcontents`), table of figures (`\tableoffigures`) and table of tables (`\tableoftables`); I need to compile the codes twice to see the changes in the pdf document.

Why can't I compile only once and see the changes?

Comment: That's just the way it is, see for example [Need to Typeset twice for correct compile?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107967)

Comment: some times more.

Comment: Because TeX does not support incremental compilation. It can't know how many chapters etc. are there in advance unless you would provide code right from the start that does a pre-definition

Comment: See also [Why is the .toc file created at end document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186674) for some more in-depth description of how the ToC is generated.

Comment: So, it seems that there is no other way to do it just in one go!

Comment: @Hepkhatduh: No, this isn't a problem nowadays, with fast computers, but it was really 'tedious', say, 20 years ago, for large documents. By the way: This has nothing to do with `TeXMaker`, `MikTeX` etc.

Comment: Alright I'll stay happy with "how it works" even if I'm too lazy to compile twice. All the answers say that i should compile more than once

Comment: @Hepkhatduh perfect

Comment: You don't have to check that the ToC etc. are updated every time you change of course. And there are several ways of automating compilations, so you only have to click once, and multiple runs are executed, see [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64)

Comment: Related: [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)